# CSS floating block resize change into new line

Tags: html, css

How can I create the effect of right hand side with only CSS when block A resize? Block C and sidebar is floating element, when I resize the block A, I hope that block C will move bellow the block A
https://jsfiddle.net/1va5xaz8/

```css
.sidebar,.c{
 float:left;
}
/* Block a will be resize*/
.a{ 
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:blue;
 margin:10px;
}

.b{
 width:100px;
 height:300px;
 background:blue;
 margin:10px;
}

.c{
 width:500px;
 height:100px;
 background:blue;
 margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
 <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
<div class="c">c</div>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Change the width of the `A` element to `100%`

Comment: Share your code so we can answer your question.

Comment: It's not clear how block `A` resizing occurs.

Comment: Remove `.a` from `.sidebar`, `float` `.c` `right`, adjust width of `.a` accordingly.

Comment: A bit hacky solution, but is it the behavior you need (try hovering the `.a` block): https://jsfiddle.net/1va5xaz8/1/ ?

Comment: I seems work for me, thank you llya

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  width: 450px;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

td {
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

tr:first-child td {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  width: 130px;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-color: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="15">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td rowspan="2">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```